# Why am I not retrieving a value at a specific location within my firebase database and am only getting nil?

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a type of polling code that once a person presses an option, a value in the Firebase database updates by one but that person cannot access it again.

Right now, I'm trying to test only one button. For reference, my database is:

"Redacted for privacy"

   -> "MainContent"

               ->-> "Polls"

                        ->->-> "GunControl"

                                ->->->-> "BackGroundChecks"

                                             ->->->->-> OptionA: 0

                                             ->->->->-> OptionB: 0

                                             ->->->->-> OptionC: 0

                                             ->->->->-> OptionD: 0

Unfortunately I do not have enough points to show a picture so please bear with it.

My Code is:

```
var counterRef = Database.database().reference()
var optionA: Int = 0
var retrieveData: Int = 0
static var pollAnswered: Bool = false


@IBAction func optionA(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Called")
    self.counterRef = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "URL Redacted For Privacy")
    print("Called2")
    updateOptionADos()
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func updateOptionADos() {

    print("Called3")

    counterRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let valString = snapshot.value as? String
        if (valString != nil && PollViewController.pollAnswered == false){
            var value = Int(valString!)
            value = value! + 1
            self.retrieveData = value!
            self.optionA = value!
            print(self.optionA)
            self.counterRef.setValue("\(String(describing: value))")
            PollViewController.pollAnswered = true
            print("Noice")
        }
        else {
            print("ya done f***** up")
        }
    })
}
```

It is supposed to call updateOptionADos() to determine what value is in the location I am trying to access (OptionA) and add 1 to it while storing that updated value in the variable optionA for later use in statistics. It builds perfectly, but I keep getting the "ya done f***** up" which tells me that the database value isn't storing for valString. Someone please help me fix this. What have I done wrong? I'm at a loss.

Comment: Please add this statement `print(snapshot.value)` above  `let valString = snapshot.value as? String` and see what does it print?

Comment: A warning told me to change it to print(snapshot.value!). It printed 0.

Comment: What does this statement `print(self.optionA)` print ?

Comment: Ok print(snapshot.value!) is definitely printing out the value in the database because I changed it to 1 and snapshot printed that value. So, if the snapshot is working, why is valString nil?

Comment: print(self.optionA) prints it at the value I set it initially as -> 0. That's because I haven't modified it yet due to the if statement diverting away from modification if valString is nil.

Comment: Can you please exactly tell the console output of  this statement `print(snapshot.value!)` , what does it print on console? please copy paste that output here

Comment: It prints only "0" for print(snapshot.value!). When I changed the database to "1", it printed only "1"

Comment: Ok and you are sure that `PollViewController.pollAnswered` is `false` and `valString ` is nil?

Comment: When I did not have the if statement, I was getting a message saying that it crashed because valString was nil and I made PollViewController.pollAnswered a static variable up top that you can see. Also the if statement would not redirect if it wasn't nil.

Comment: Ok then there can only be on reason here, `snapshot.value` is not of type `String`, now to make sure we need to check the value of `counterRef` what does it point to and also we need to check the actual db structure, please check that since you are not showing in the OP

Comment: counterRef references a URL directly to the value I want in the database. For the db structure, I couldn't upload a picture but the text I wrote out is the same. -> represents the level each data is on.

Comment: I think that the reference is correct because print(snapshot.value!) is printing the value I put at that location in the database. Would it actually be an array of Strings even though there is only one value there?

Comment: Yes, it is a path specifically for OptionA. Also my console says this: 

0, 
This is valString nil, 
0, 
ya done f***** up. I added the commas btw.

Comment: I figured it out! You were right, it was not a String but an Int! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great, congrats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the value and try to cast it as a String:

> let valString = snapshot.value as? String

And then you cast that string to an Int:

> var value = Int(valString!)

If you are storing the count as an Integer, not a string, `snapshot.value as? String` will return nil, as it is not a String.